# Как вырезать квадратные скобки и кавычки из списка?

Tags: python, синтаксис

Как вырезать квадратные скобки и кавычки из списка?

Есть список

> ```
> [['==РАСПРОДАЖА=='], ['Вытяжка для настенного монтажа'], ['Компактная
> посудомоечная машина'], ['Газовая варочная панель'], ['Комплект для
> смены цвета'], ['Комплект для смены цвета'], ['Комплект для смены
> цвета'], ['Комплект для смены цвета'], ['Кольцо для WOK-конфорки'],
> ['Кольцо для WOK-конфорки'], ['Любителям итальянской кухни: набор
> PastaPassion'], ['Защитный кожух Textile Protect для TDS16..'],
> ['Телескопические направляющие для 3 уровней'], ['Мясорубка + адаптер
> для кухонного комбайна'], ['Насадка-терка для сыра / шоколада'],
> ['Насадка для приготовления спагетти'], ['Декоративная планка; цвет
> \\сталь\\'], ['Комплект для установки компактных посудомоечных
> машин']]
> ```

Нужно что бы список был без `['   ']`, и без первого элемента `['==РАСПРОДАЖА==']`

Код

```
#чтение списка из Excel файла
read_nw = [] # создание нового списка
with open('items.csv', newline='') as file_2:  
    reader = csv.reader(file_2)
    for row in reader:
        read_nw.append(row)
        print(row)
    print(str(read_nw))
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Например так (я немножко изменил ваш код, значит, используйте тот вместо вашего):

```
with open('test.csv', newline='') as file_2:  
    reader = csv.reader(file_2)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        for el in row:
            print(f"{el:55}", end=" ")         # 55 - максимальная длина
        print()
```

---

Вывод:

> ```
> Вытяжка для настенного монтажа                          
> Компактная посудомоечная машина                         
> Газовая варочная панель                                 
> Комплект для смены цвета                                
> Комплект для смены цвета                                
> Комплект для сменыцвета                                 
> Комплект для смены цвета                                
> Кольцо для WOK-конфорки                                 
> Кольцо для WOK-конфорки                                 
> Любителям итальянской кухни: наборPastaPassion          
> Защитный кожух Textile Protect для TDS16..              
> Телескопические направляющие для 3 уровней              
> Мясорубка + адаптердля кухонного комбайна               
> Насадка-терка для сыра / шоколада                       
> Насадка для приготовления спагетти                      
> Декоративная планка; цвет\сталь\                        
> Комплект для установки компактных посудомоечныхмашин
> ```

---

*Примечание:*

Ваша последняя команда `file.close()` совсем излишня, т.к. после выхода из `with` файл закрывается автоматически.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
a = ''

m = []

for i in read_nw[1:]:
    a += ''.join(i)+', '
m.append(a[0:-2])

print(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

Наиболее быстрая реализация:

```
sps=[['==РАСПРОДАЖА=='], ['Вытяжка для настенного монтажа'], 
     ['Компактная посудомоечная машина'], ['Газовая варочная панель'], 
     ['Комплект для смены цвета'], ['Комплект для смены цвета'], 
     ['Комплект для смены цвета'], ['Комплект для смены цвета'], 
     ['Кольцо для WOK-конфорки'], ['Кольцо для WOK-конфорки'], 
     ['Любителям итальянской кухни: набор PastaPassion'], 
     ['Защитный кожух Textile Protect для TDS16..'],
     ['Телескопические направляющие для 3 уровней'], 
     ['Мясорубка + адаптер для кухонного комбайна'], 
     ['Насадка-терка для сыра / шоколада'], 
     ['Насадка для приготовления спагетти'], 
     ['Декоративная планка; цвет сталь'], 
     ['Комплект для установки компактных посудомоечныхмашин']
     ]
n_sps=[]
for lst in sps[1:]:
    n_sps.extend(lst)
```

Результат:

```
print(n_sps)
['Вытяжка для настенного монтажа', 'Компактная посудомоечная машина', 'Газовая варочная панель', 'Комплект для смены цвета', 'Комплект для смены цвета', 'Комплект для смены цвета', 'Комплект для смены цвета', 'Кольцо для WOK-конфорки', 'Кольцо для WOK-конфорки', 'Любителям итальянской кухни: набор PastaPassion', 'Защитный кожух Textile Protect для TDS16..', 'Телескопические направляющие для 3 уровней', 'Мясорубка + адаптер для кухонного комбайна', 'Насадка-терка для сыра / шоколада', 'Насадка для приготовления спагетти', 'Декоративная планка; цвет сталь', 'Комплект для установки компактных посудомоечныхмашин']
```

Если же вам надо все выводить единой строкой (как внезапно оказалось), то замените последние строки на:

```
n_sps=""
for lst in sps[1:]:
    n_sps=n_sps+lst[0]
```

Результат:

```
 print(n_sps)
Вытяжка для настенного монтажаКомпактная посудомоечная машинаГазовая варочная панельКомплект для смены цветаКомплект для смены цветаКомплект для смены цветаКомплект для смены цветаКольцо для WOK-конфоркиКольцо для WOK-конфоркиЛюбителям итальянской кухни: набор PastaPassionЗащитный кожух Textile Protect для TDS16..Телескопические направляющие для 3 уровнейМясорубка + адаптер для кухонного комбайнаНасадка-терка для сыра / шоколадаНасадка для приготовления спагеттиДекоративная планка; цвет стальКомплект для установки компактных посудомоечныхмашин
```